# Are the two witnesses the prophet like Moses?

Tags: prophecy, moses

> Heaven must hold this one (Christ) within itself until the times of restoration of all things of which God spoke through the mouth of his holy prophets of old. In fact, Moses said: ‘Jehovah your God will raise up for you from among your brothers a prophet like me. You must listen to whatever he tells you. Indeed, anyone who does not listen to that Prophet will be completely destroyed from among the people.’(Acts 3:21-23).

The two witnesses of Revelation 11 perform miracles "like" Moses and Elijah:

> These have the authority to shut up the sky so that no rain may fall during the days of their prophesying (*Elijah*), and they have authority over the waters to turn them into blood and to strike the earth with every sort of plague as often as they wish (*Moses*) (Revelation 11:5,6).

What's more, the two witnesses perform a deliverance from a world empire, just like Moses. We know this because after their ministry of 3.5 years ends the people of God are released from captivity to the wild beast (Rev. 11:2,3; Rev. 13:5). The time frame is exactly the same (1260 days/42 months). It is *because of the plagues* that were wrought upon the wild beast empire by the two witnesses who are acting just "like" Moses who brought plagues on the Egyptian world empire, that God's people are set free.

The context of Peter's words in Acts 3:21-23 are the times of restoration of all things. He is speaking of the *future* times when the two witnesses perform these miracles. He makes that clear with the words "heaven must hold this one (Christ) until...". During the times of the restoration of all things, it is also the two witnesses who will restore all things (as the prophet Elijah). Jesus Christ made that clear:

> In reply he said: "E·liʹjah is indeed coming and will restore all things." (Matt. 17:11).

The "restoration" connection here further points to the fact that the two witnesses act as the prophet like Moses.

Comment: Since the complaint was made that I asked too many (rhetorical) questions the last time, I have adjusted the question and reposted in a simplified form as per the rules of the forum. Perhaps Anne would like to answer this question with a simple yes or no answer?

Comment: I only voted to close this Q 22 hours after you commented to me. My reason is that you invoke 4 Bible texts, not 1 (which is what Hermeneutics requires). Jumping from OT to NT here means you ask about a topic, not a verse. Once you get the hang of how this site works your Qs should be acceptable. I'd love to answer on the topic of the 2 witnesses of Revelation, but that would have to be posted on the Christianity site. I assure you that there cannot be a simple "Yes" or "No" answer to whether the 2 witnesses are the prophet like Moses!

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to the stack! Anne is right, this isn't really how the site is designed to work - you don't gather together various passages and frame your own solution, asking for a Yes/No answer. It's down to each *Answer* to do this kind of legwork. It's not really just about how the site works either - *hermeneutics* as a discipline begins with the text and starts by examining it within its own context. You've got a theological question here, but it's skipped over the hermeneutical stages of examining the individual texts to see what they say *in their own right*.

Answer (score 1):

This question still has several facets with which I will deal only briefly as these questions have been addressed several times in other places on this site.

1. **"The Prophet"**

The famous passage in Deut 18:15-19 prophesying "The Prophet" like Moses was, according to Acts 3:22, 23, fulfilled in Jesus.

2. **Elijah**

Mal 4:5, 6 predicts the coming of Elijah before the arrival of Messiah.  The NT claims these as fulfilled in the ministry of John the Baptist in places like Matt 11:13, 14, 17:11-14, Mark 9:12, 13, Luke 1:17.

However, the “*great and terrible day of the Lord*” (Mal 4:5) clearly also has eschatological fulfilment and confirmed by the indirect allusions to Elijah in the book of Revelation.

3. **"Moses and Elijah and the Two Witnesses"**

In Rev 11:3-13. The identity of these two witnesses is provided by a number of clues such as:

Those alluding to **Elijah**:

- v3: they prophesy for 1260 days (3½ years, Ja 5:17, Lu 4:25) in sackcloth
- v5: they call fire down from heaven (1 Ki 18:37, 38, 2 Ki 1:9-14)
- v11: they are caught up to heaven (2 Ki 2:11)
- v6: they shut up the heavens (1 Ki 17:1)

Those alluding to **Moses**:

- v6: they initiate a plague of blood (Ex 7:14-18)
- v6: they strike the earth with plagues (Ex 9:14-16)

Other General Clues

- v10: also called two prophets (Moses and Elijah)
- v4: also called two olive trees - an allusion to Zech 4: 3-12 and the two who serve the Lord of the earth. Rom 11:17, 24, James 3:12 use this figure of the church and its character.
- v4: also called two lampstands - probably two churches or two aspects of the same church on the basis of Rev 1:20 which equates the symbol of the lampstand with a church as the light of the world (Matt 5:.14-16). If this is correct, then the two lampstands are symbols of God’s true church from the time of Jesus to His second advent.
- v3: 1260 days is a parallel to the 1260 days of the woman of Rev 12 which is a clear allusion to a church.

Thus, Mal 4 appears to have elements that have dual fulfilments.